# Unity3D sqlite multiple "System.Data.dll" problem

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use sql-lite in my Unity3D project. In fact, I used it in the past now I am trying to update it. 
Unity version and sql-lite version has changed since then.

Now I get an error like this;

> error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been
>   imported: 'C:\Users[username]\Documents\Unity Games[your program
>   name]\Assets\System.Data.dll' and 'C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\NetStandard\compat\2.0.0\shims\netfx\System.Data.dll'.
>   Remove one of the duplicate references.

As I understand from the message that, sqlite wants to use its own System.Data.dll file, but it has the same library name in .net. So this causes a conflict and unity throws an error.

I tried to delete the System.Data.dll and its meta filewhich is in Assets file, but did not work. I also tried to change the file name in Asset folder but nothing changed...

Do you have a solution for this problem? I have tried in both Unity 2018 and 2019 versions.

**Additional info may help others:** In the past I had a problem with sqlite in my games. I had handled the situation like putting or copying my data sqlite file (filename.sqlite as an example) into the folder:

> C:\Users[username]\AppData\LocalLow\[app folder]\[app
>   name]\filename.sqlite

Because unity looks for the folder in script and that folder exists in windows which I mentioned above;

> string filepath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" +
>   "filename.sqlite";

This helped me to solve my problem in the past. Now I am stuck with a different problem...

**Solution:**
Here is the solution by the guied of Алексей Кудряшов and blending my sqlite package. Thanks to him for his suggestion.

1- I deleted all all Plugins, GoogleMobileAds, PlayServicesResolver etc.

2- I first installed my admob package back

3- I installed everything manually in the link;
[SQLite4Unity](https://github.com/robertohuertasm/SQLite4Unity3d/raw/master/SQLite4Unity3d.zip)

4- I installed sqlite package but while installing it, I select none and i installed only "Mono.Data.Sqlite" file. If you have it or if you find it you can manually add it into Asset folder of Unity3D. Also you may find it from;
[SQLite web page](https://sqlite.org/download.html)

5- Then Console said me that there is a conflict in x86 and x64 folders for sqlite3.dll file so, I clicked the x86 folder, then clicked sqlite3.dll then in the inspector panel I disabled everything.

6- Then I imported "using SQLite4Unity3d;" for my data script.

7- I also imported "using Mono.Data.Sqlite;"

8- Then everything worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use another SQLite wrapper?
e.g. [SQLite for unity](https://github.com/robertohuertasm/SQLite4Unity3d)

You can just remove your current SQLite plugin and replace it with this one.
Don't forget to re-launch unity and unity HUB, cuz unity will keep DLLs in the memory until it restarts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I instantly tried it but it messed up everything. I guess it would be a better choice if I find a solution to my exact problem.

Comment: yet still I am trying it, I have an error like;

The type or namespace name 'SqliteConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

but I am pretty sure i have imported using SQLite4Unity3d;

Comment: did you check examples from the SQLite4Unity? As I can see there is some strange **usings** you can check their own implementation here : [link](https://github.com/robertohuertasm/SQLite4Unity3d/blob/master/Example/Assets/Scripts/SQLite.cs)

Comment: I blended your suggestion and my sqlite package and compiling now. If it works I will edit and share my solution.

Comment: Thanks blending worked. Now I am editing my question and adding the solution according to your guide.